# Solving ode similar to Adler's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to find the exact solution of the following form:

$$f'(t) = ae^{-bt} - K \sin(f(t)) $$

It is similar to Adler's equation, but it can not be solved by the method for finding exact solution of Adler's equation. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Follow the method in http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=223:

Let $x=\tan\dfrac{f}{2}$ ,

Then $x'=\dfrac{ae^{-bt}x^2}{2}-Kx+\dfrac{ae^{-bt}}{2}$

Let $x=-\dfrac{2e^{bt}y'}{ay}$ ,

Then $x'=-\dfrac{2e^{bt}y''}{ay}-\dfrac{2be^{bt}y'}{ay}+\dfrac{2e^{bt}(y')^2}{ay^2}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{2e^{bt}y''}{ay}-\dfrac{2be^{bt}y'}{ay}+\dfrac{2e^{bt}(y')^2}{ay^2}=\dfrac{2e^{bt}(y')^2}{ay^2}+\dfrac{2Ke^{bt}y'}{ay}+\dfrac{ae^{-bt}}{2}$

$\dfrac{2e^{bt}y''}{ay}+\dfrac{2(b+K)e^{bt}y'}{ay}+\dfrac{ae^{-bt}}{2}=0$

$4y''+4(b+K)y'+a^2e^{-2bt}y=0$