# Is there a way to solve the following ODE analytically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to see if I can solve the following ODE analytically:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \sin(x+y) - e^x.$$

If I substitute: $z:= x+y,$ I get:

$$\frac{dz}{dx}= 1 + \sin(z) - e^x.$$

I can't separate the variables, nor I can use any integrating factor, as it's not an exact ODE/ So is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+y$ ,

Then $y=z-x$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dz}{dx}-1$

$\therefore\dfrac{dz}{dx}-1=\sin z-e^x$

$\dfrac{dz}{dx}=\sin z+1-e^x$

Which is similar as [Solving ode similar to Adler's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291686) and follow the method in http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=223:

Let $u=\tan\dfrac{z}{2}$ ,

Then $z=2\tan^{-1}u$

$\dfrac{dz}{dx}=\dfrac{2}{u^2+1}\dfrac{du}{dx}$

$\therefore\dfrac{2}{u^2+1}\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{2u}{u^2+1}+1-e^x$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{(1-e^x)u^2}{2}+u+\dfrac{1-e^x}{2}$

Which converts to a Riccati ODE.

Let $u=\dfrac{2}{(e^x-1)v}\dfrac{dv}{dx}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{2}{(e^x-1)v}\dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2}-\dfrac{2}{(e^x-1)v^2}\left(\dfrac{dv}{dx}\right)^2-\dfrac{2e^x}{(e^x-1)^2v}\dfrac{dv}{dx}$

$\therefore\dfrac{2}{(e^x-1)v}\dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2}-\dfrac{2}{(e^x-1)v^2}\left(\dfrac{dv}{dx}\right)^2-\dfrac{2e^x}{(e^x-1)^2v}\dfrac{dv}{dx}=-\dfrac{2}{(e^x-1)v^2}\left(\dfrac{dv}{dx}\right)^2+\dfrac{2}{(e^x-1)v}\dfrac{dv}{dx}+\dfrac{1-e^x}{2}$

$\dfrac{2}{(e^x-1)v}\dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2}-\dfrac{2(2e^x-1)}{(e^x-1)^2v}\dfrac{dv}{dx}+\dfrac{e^x-1}{2}=0$

$(e^x-1)\dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2}-(2e^x-1)\dfrac{dv}{dx}+\dfrac{(e^x-1)^3}{4}v=0$

Let $t=e^x$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{dv}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dx}=e^x\dfrac{dv}{dt}=t\dfrac{dv}{dt}$

$\dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(t\dfrac{dv}{dt}\right)=\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(t\dfrac{dv}{dt}\right)\dfrac{dt}{dx}=\left(t\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}+\dfrac{dv}{dt}\right)t=t^2\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}+t\dfrac{dv}{dt}$

$\therefore(t-1)\left(t^2\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}+t\dfrac{dv}{dt}\right)-(2t-1)t\dfrac{dv}{dt}+\dfrac{(t-1)^3}{4}v=0$

$t^2(t-1)\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}+t(t-1)\dfrac{dv}{dt}-t(2t-1)\dfrac{dv}{dt}+\dfrac{(t-1)^3}{4}v=0$

$t^2(t-1)\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}-t^2\dfrac{dv}{dt}+\dfrac{(t-1)^3}{4}v=0$

$\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}-\dfrac{1}{t-1}\dfrac{dv}{dt}+\dfrac{(t-1)^2}{4t^2}v=0$

$\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}-\dfrac{1}{t-1}\dfrac{dv}{dt}+\left(\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{2t}+\dfrac{1}{4t^2}\right)v=0$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, the second link isn't working, showing a Bad Gateway warning.. Could you please give me the correct link?